# Jquery Scrolltop not working in IE for div scrollpoint. Working perfectly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Ive setup a basic code where my div containing a table overflows into a scroll.
I want to be able to click on an item in the table displaying a div over the top and then once done return to the scroll position i was in on the previous div. In Firefox my code works perfectly and does everything as expected, but in IE i get no errors or functionality. The page basically works as normal without returning to my scrollpoint, just the top of the table.

```
function previousPage(){        
        toggleDivEvent('TableDisplay');
        $('#TableDisplay').data('scroll');
        $('#<%= buttonGoBack.ClientID%>').hide();             
    }


function newUserClick() {
         $('#TableDisplay').data('scroll',$('#TableDisplay').scrollTop());
        $('#<%= buttonGoBack.ClientID%>').show();             
        clearItems();
        toggleDivEvent('ModifyUser');                                         
    }
```

Cant really specify what all the other code does, as its quite a large page. Basically my div containing the table called #TableDisplay is given an attribute 'scroll' with the scroll position when the new user function is clicked, which hides the TableDisplay div and shows the newuser div. previousPage function does the opposite and returns back to the TableDisplay div using the scroll attribute to find the scroll position and return to it.

Comment: Problem Solved. For anyone that ever has the same problem, i removed the set attribute and assigned a variable the current scroll position using variable = (#div).scrollTop(). Then using (#div).scrollTop(variable) i was able to get the div to find its position. Variable was globally defined at the top.